# Strange .htaccess and base URL redirect happening

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess, base-url

I have an odd scenario that I cannot figure out. When Auto-redirect to Base URL is set to 301 or 302, the homepage of my website redirects correctly to what I have defined as my base URL (I am using non-www as my base). However, when this is on and I try to visit one of my subpages using the www. version, it sends me back to my homepage. 
IE:
www.example.com redirects correctly to example.com
www.example.com/subpage, also sends me to example.com - not the correct subpage.

I thought that I may be able to circumvent this by disabling the base URL redirect and then manually modifying my .htaccess file. I used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this case it is a similar situation... when visiting www.example.com I am correctly redirected to example.com. However, when I visit www.example.com/subpageI am incorrectly redirected to example.com/index.php

I found a few variations of the redirect code and all had the same results.

I then tried to manually redirect individual pages, also to no avail.

I also tried setting a manual redirect through the Magento URL Rewrites in the dashboard.

Nothing seems to work and I am out of ideas. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been resolved. This thread was recommended to me by the system after posting my message: [Redirect 'non www prefix to 'www' prefix still not working after disabling 'Auto-redirect to Base URL'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/redirect-non-www-prefix-to-www-prefix-still-not-working-after-disabling-auto?rq=1)

I disabled base url redirects and then moved the code to the beginning of .htaccess and this did the trick.

Thank you for having a very reliable and accurate 'related posts' feature.